# bootstrap navbar dropdown hover glitch

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm currently working on my first project, and I've learnt a lot so far, but I've hit a small stumbling block, in trying to make a user experience as clean as possible, I'm working on the navbar at the moment, trying to have the dropdown menu automatically appear when the user hovers over the toggle, the issue is sometimes the dropdown menu appears to glitch out as shown in the clips below, I've spent today researching on Google and reading the bootstrap manual but I haven't been able to find a solution to this, if anyone could guide me in the right direction so I can learn why this is happening I'd really appreciate it, I've included the HTML and CSS below the clips, thank you very much.

[image: clip01] [image: clip02]

css

```
.dropdown:hover > .dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
}
.dropdown > .dropdown-toggle:active {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<!-- Required meta tags -->
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

<title>Hello, world!</title>

<style>
    .dropdown:hover > .dropdown-menu {
        display: block;
    }
    .dropdown > .dropdown-toggle:active {
        pointer-events: none;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
<a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
<button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
<span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
</button>

<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
<ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
<li class="nav-item dropdown">
<a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
Dropdown
</a>
<div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
<a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
<a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
<div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
<a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
</div>
</li>
<li class="nav-item dropdown">
<a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
Dropdown
</a>
<div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
<a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
<a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
<div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
<a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
</div>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
</nav>

<!-- Optional JavaScript -->
<!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because when moving the mouse pointer down from the link to the menu, there is a small space when the pointer is no longer over the link nor over the menu, so the :hover state is deactivated and the menu disappears.

If you move the mouse fast enough from the link to the menu, the menu won't disappear because you "beat" the time it takes to transition from hover to default.

The dropdown menu will usually be styled with `position: absolute;`, which means you can use the `top` property to adjust its position, until there is no gap between the menu and the link, for example: `top: 0px` or even a negative value like `-1px`. Adjusting `margin-top` with a negative value is another option.

Comment: perfect, your reply is much appreciated, thank you very much.

Comment: `margin-top: -1px` worked great! With top I had to determine the exact pixel height of the menu rather than just setting how much I'd like it adjusted with margin.